# Is it necessary to have a heading of <section> in HTML5

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Is it necessary to have a heading of `<section>` in HTML5 like mentioned here http://blog.whatwg.org/is-not-just-a-semantic

Sometime on a page we have some elements which are related and can be combined in a `<section id="semantic name">` instead `<div id="semantic name">` But we don't have any Heading for that..

Is it OK to use `<section>` without having `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` inside

Answer (score 6):

[According to the HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/), you should not use `<section>` if there is no natural heading for it. Also, they say:

> The section element represents a generic document or application section…The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead.

Also, [check out this nifty flowchart](http://html5doctor.com/wp-content/uploads/HTML5Doctor-sectioning-flowchart.png) to decide what element is best to use in your situations.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not required.

You can easily check this by reading the [definition of the `section` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/sections.html#the-section-element) ("should" is not "must") or by validating your HTML.

The [W3C validator will report a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26185873/1591669) when no heading is used, but a warning is not an error.

Comment: It is not required but a `section` without a `heading` is a `div`

Comment: @Gezzasa: No, a heading-less `section` still creates an entry in the document outline, a `div` doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

Its only necessary if it wont [validate] (http://validator.w3.org)

The use of section tags is to convey the structure of your content, like a book is split into chapters, paragraphs, etc

If your page is mash of images to look like a magazine cover you may not have a need for adding any sections. You'll most likely still want structure for navigation but that's not done using sections.

I would say any page containing chunks of text (most pages) should use a section tag rather than a div. keep the divs for controlling layout only.

My best advice is to see how your site looks in a text only browser, or other accessible client. It amazing how rubbish most sites are designed for accessibility. My take is that section tags are an attempt to improve that.