# W3C HTML validation error - Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am getting a warning when I try to validate my page in https://validator.w3.org:

> Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections.

My code is as below:

```
<section id="slider-wrapper-new">
    <div class="slider-container-new">
        // some code..
    </div>
</section>
```

How can I remove this error? Do I need to add `h1`-`h6` tags inside the section heading?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Either:

1. Add a heading (`h1`, ..., `h6`) tag to your `section` element.
2. Replace your `section` element with a `div` element.
3. Ignore the warning. The message you're seeing is a **non-normative** usage recommendation, as per the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/sections.html#the-section-element) (highlighting mine):

> The theme of each `section` **should** be identified, typically by
>   including a heading (`h1`-`h6` element) as a child of the `section`
>   element.

Answer (score 16):

Your code is valid (if you use a closing `</section>` instead of `</div>`).

The W3C validator reports a *warning*, not an *error.*

While it is useful to provide a heading for each sectioning content element, it is [not required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26185942/1591669).

The only way to prevent this warning when using sectioning content elements is, well, to follow the advice by providing a heading content element. If you’d use a `div` instead, your document outline would be different and likely wrong (if you used `section` correctly in the first place).

Answer (score 2):

You have to put an h1,h2,h3 inside your section:

```
<section id="slider-wrapper-new">
 <div class="slider-container-new">
  <h3>My Title</h3>
    // some code..
 </div>
```