# Warning: Article lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all articles

Tags: css, html, validation

I have `<article>`, `<section>`, `<header>` and everything seems fine, but the HTML Validator returns error:

**Warning: Article lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all articles.**

Can you please advise me where is the problem?

```html
<div class="item column-1" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <article>
    <section class="article-intro clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
      <header>
        <h2>My header text</h2>
      </header>
      <p>My paragraph text</p>

      <p>
        <img src="/images/myimage.jpg" alt="image alt">
      </p>

    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [w3c html validation error - Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155024/w3c-html-validation-error-section-lacks-heading-consider-using-h2-h6-elements)

Answer (score 4):

What the validator is complaining about is the lack of headings in your article blocks. As in, your article, not the nested sections.
The optimum structure would be something like:

```
<article>
  <h1>Some heading</h1>
  <p>Content of the article ... </p>
</article>
```

You're not doing anything wrong by the way, keep in mind that it's just a warning, not an error.

P.S well done for trying to follow the W3C standards, btw

Comment: Thank you!

Unfortunately I am using Joomla and I cannot change the html exactly as I want.

This is the closest what I could get, but still not Valid


    <article>
        <header class="article-header clearfix">
            <h2></h2>
        </header>
        <section class="article-intro clearfix">
            <p></p>
        </section>
    </article>

Answer (score 3):

Use `aria-label="article"`

```
<article aria-label="article">
  <p>Content of the article ... </p>
</article>
```