# warning Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections. for code challenge 1-3 old masters

Tags: html, forms

here is the code i am using and the warning message from w3 validator at the bottom. I cannot seem to eliminate the errors white keeping my section and footers without changing fonts.
Open the code1-3_txt.html file from the tutorial1 c code3 folder. Enter your name and the date in the head section of the document and save the file as code1-3.html to the same location.
2. Add an attribute to the opening  tag to set the language of the page to “en” (for English).
3. Within the head section of the document do the following:a. Set the character encoding of the file to utf-8.b. Set the page title to Coding Challenge 1-3.c. Link the file to designs stored in the code1-3_styles.css style sheet file.
4. Within the page body, insert an h1 heading containing the text Drawings from the Old Masters.
5. After the h1 heading, insert six section elements using the  tag.

```
`enter code here`<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Coding Challenge 1-3</title>
   <link href="code1-3_styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head> 
<body>
  <h1>Drawings from the Old Masters</h1>
  
  <section>
      <img src="drawing01.png" alt="Leonardo da Vinci"/>
      <footer>The Battle of Anghieari <br />&mdash; Leonardo da Vinci</footer>
  </section>        
  <section>
      <img src="drawing02.png" alt="Jacopo da Pontormo"/>
      <footer>Study of a Youth <br />&mdash; Jacopo da Pontormo</footer>
  </section>
  <section>
      <img src="drawing03.png" alt="Raphael"/>
      <footer>The Nativity <br />&mdash; Raphael</footer>
   </section>
   <section>
       <img src="drawing04.png" alt="Peter Paul Rubens"/>
       <footer>Head of a Maid <br />&mdash; Peter Paul Rubens</footer>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="drawing05.png" alt="Andrea del Sarto"/>
        <footer>Head of a Young Woman <br /> &mdash; Andrea del Sarto</footer>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="drawing06.png" alt="Titian"/>
        <footer>Head of a Youth <br />&mdash; Titian</footer>
    </section>          
</body>
</html>`enter code here`
```

just need some guidance
this is the Warning i get :

Warning: Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections.

From line 20, column 3; to line 20, column 11

/h1>↩  ↩  ↩      <i

Comment: Why does everything need to be in section tags? Why not replace those with div's and just be done with it?

Comment: i apologize i am a bit of a beginner, i have tried to use div's as my research pointed but when i substitute <section> for <div> the font changes in the output and doesnt match the challange .

Comment: 2. Add an attribute to the opening <html> tag to set the language of the page to “en” (for English).  3. Within the head section of the document do the following:a. Set the character encoding of the file to utf-8.b. Set the page title to Coding Challenge 1-3.c. Link the file to designs stored in the code1-3_styles.css style sheet file.  4. Within the page body, insert an h1 heading containing the text Drawings from the Old Masters.  5. After the h1 heading, insert six section elements using the <section>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [w3c html validation error - Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155024/w3c-html-validation-error-section-lacks-heading-consider-using-h2-h6-elements)