# Naming a HTML5 <section> with inline <span> rather than block level element

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

As I understand it, good HTML5 practice is to name all sections using h2-h6 tags:

```
<section id='chapter_one' class='chapter'>
  <h3>Chapter One</h3>
  <p>My site has lots of content.</p>
</section>
```

Without the  element the w3c Validator gives "**Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections**".  That's fine, but is there a way to use an in-line element rather than a block element for the section label?

```
<section id='chapter_one' class='chapter'>
  <p>Welcome to <span>Chapter One</span> of my fine content rich site.</p>
</section>
```

References: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/18/the-importance-of-sections/ and [w3c html validation error - Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155024/w3c-html-validation-error-section-lacks-heading-consider-using-h2-h6-elements) and [Is it necessary to have a heading of <section> in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544671/is-it-necessary-to-have-a-heading-of-section-in-html5)

Answer (score 0):

No.

As the HTML5 spec defines in [*Headings and sections*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/sections.html#headings-and-sections):

> The first element of heading content in an element of sectioning content represents the heading for that section.

And the [*heading content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/dom.html#heading-content-0) category contains:

> `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`

Comment: How about aria-labelledby="chapter_{{id}}" <span id="chapter_{{id}}">

Comment: @Bryce: WAI-ARIA doesn’t affect the document outline. (It can help assistive technologies, but it’s not necessarily used by other consumers of your HTML.)